# Assign of user input number to array in char data type

Tags: java, arrays, char

I'm trying to ask the user to input a three digit number, then have the code assign a new variable to the char of each digit using charAt() and put each digit into an array.  So far it allowed me to input a number, but then it stops and doesn't do anything else, so I think it is a problem with this part.  How would you do that?

The purpose is so that the computer with generate a three digit number, ask the user to input a number, then analyze the numbers to see how many digits of the guessed number are the same as in the generated number and how many of the correct digits are in the correct place.  So if the generated number is 180, and you guess 481, then the digits correct would be 2 and the places correct would be 1.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        char[] array = new char [3];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            array[i] = (char)(Math.random() * 9);
        }

        char[] guess = {0, 0, 0};

        System.out.println("I have a three digit number with no repeating digits. Guess the number.");

        while (guess != array){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            char number1 = input.next().charAt(0);
            char number2 = input.next().charAt(1);
            char number3 = input.next().charAt(2);

            guess[0] = number1;
            guess[1] = number2;
            guess[2] = number3;

            int digit = 0;
            int place = 0;
            for(int n = 0; n < array.length; n++){
                for(int d = 0; d < array.length; d++){
                    if(array[n] == guess[d]){
                        digit++;
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int r = 0; r < array.length; r++){
                if(array[r] == guess[r]){
                    place++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Correct digits: " + digit);
            System.out.println("Correct places: " + place);
        }
        System.out.println("Congratulations, you got it");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you plz share your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String num = input.next();
char number1 = num.charAt(0);
char number2 = num.charAt(1);
char number3 = num.charAt(2);
```

To fix the problems you'll run into after this:

```
array[i] = (char) (Math.random() * 9 + '0');
```

You need to store the character correctly. Before, you were storing the ascii codes 0 - 9.

```
while (guess[0] != array[0] || guess[1] != array[1] || guess[2] != array[2]){
```

You need to compare each value of the array individually.

You need to store the number before sampling the characters.

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer. That is why someone downvoted you

Comment: I can't comment yet, so I was planning on editing my answer. Should I just avoid answers that require clarification completely till I have enough rep? (Genuine question, sounds a little snarky in text)

Comment: "Should I just avoid answers that require clarification completely till I have enough rep" Yes.